# Speed up Get Data from Table or alternative way to generate auto-filtered list?

Tags: excel, filtering, powerquery

Goal: Use a drop down as a filter to extract a subset from table1 into a new range. For instance, if table 1 is a grid of cities and states, use a drop down of "Alabama, Alaska, etc", select "Pennsylvania" and have a new range populated with "Philadelphia, Pittsburgh, etc"

Scenario: I have a table of events along with their location details. I have a data validation drop down with locations from that table. When I select a specific location, I want Excel to look at that table and create a filtered list in a new tab. (aside, this is stupidly simple and fast to do in Google Sheets with =filter(A1:B5,A1:A5=D1) when I have the state dropdown in D1.)

Setup: I currently have the system working based on using Get Data from Table (new PowerQuery) using the technique described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gK2yBpiITvI&t=2s). It works great except it's slow as molasses. My table is less than 1000 rows long and the output is between 5-20 matches, but it takes about 70 seconds to refresh after I change the drop-down.

Are there any other ideas for doing this or methods for speeding up the query?

Particulars: Table1 is on Sheet1!A1:U1000 and the locations are in Col B. New range starts in Sheet2!B10. Dropdown is in Sheet3!T11.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason you don't just create a PivotTable based on the data, and filter the PivotTable using a Slicer on the City/State field?

Comment: @jeffreyweir Pivots are my go-to, but I'm building this for another team and I think the pivot/slicer interface would be less intuitive than a drop-down.

Comment: OK. That said, Slicers are pretty intuitive. And you can always hide the scary bits of a Pivot from the end user, or hide the PivotTable entirely and just bring the bits of interest into the grid using GETPIVOTDATA. You can also fake a dropdown that syncs to a Pivot with no code whatsoever as I talk about at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/

Comment: Another idea is to use the Advanced Filter and a bit of VBA, which is fast as lightning. But can you elaborate a little further on what you are doing, and what users will see? A screenshot would help.

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067108/how-to-direct-jump-on-specific-cell-in-excel/47067645#47067645 to see how the Advanced Filter might be leveraged in a situation like this.